# XNA Aquatic Distortion Effect

Tags: xna, c#, effects

I'm currently developing a 2D, top-down Windows Phone 7 game involving the surface of a pond.  I'm trying to make the surface feel like actual water (as opposed to just a blue background with sprites drawn on top of it), and one of the effects I'm looking into is a sort of aquatic distortion effect.  Basically, something similar to the first few seconds of this: http://youtu.be/1BpRsjF7QTM?t=3m17s

Any idea on how to do this in XNA? I'm sure I could figure out how to apply the answer to my particular application, but if it helps, my game involves a lot of ripples and I'd like to specifically distort the areas around and just behind the expanding sprite-based ripples.

Thanks!

Comment: Look into HLSL, distortion effects are not complicated to do using a simple pixel shader. The Bloom sample on the XNA site is a good place to start. Also, Aquaria is open source ;)  http://hg.icculus.org/icculus/aquaria/file/deb98b4addea

Comment: I just noticed that you are targeting the Windows Phone 7, in that case forget my HLSL suggestion (XNA does not give you access to programmable shaders on the phones). Instead, here is the ripple effect code from Aquaria (Line 615): http://hg.icculus.org/icculus/aquaria/file/deb98b4addea/BBGE/AfterEffect.cpp#l615

Answer (score 5):

Render your scene to a render target.

Render your render target to the screen on a procedurally-generated full-screen mesh with animated vertices or texture coordinates.